# Vitali's convergence theorem - converse

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

We know by Vitali Converse that:

let $\mu(E)<\infty$ and {$h_n$} is a sequence of "nonnegative" integrable functions that converges pointwise $a.e.$ on $E$ to $h=0$.

Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_Eh_n=0$ iff {$h_n$} is uniformly integrable over $E$.

Why it does not hold without the assumption that {$h_n$} is nonnegative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E = [-1,1]$ with Lebesgue measure and take $h_n = n (1_{(0, 1/n)} - 1_{(-1/n, 0)})$.  We have $h_n \to 0$ pointwise and $\int h_n = 0$ for every $n$,  but $\{h_n\}$ is not uniformly integrable.

Comment: Does it converge pointwise a.e to $h=0$?

Comment: @Anita: $h_n$ converges pointwise to $-1_{(-1,0)}$.

Comment: That's the point, it should converge to $h=0$ pointwise a.e.

Comment: @Anita: Thanks, I missed that.  I modified my example.

Comment: @Anita: Oh, but I see you got there first, by 26 seconds :)

Comment: Yes, I'll delete my answer then :)